# Why custom proxy timeouts instead of going to fault sequence?

Tags: wso2-esb

I'm trying to create a custom proxy which would respond with a SoapFault when the request payload is an illegal xml, but no matter what I try the faultSequence doesn't get called.

This problem doesn't occur when using PassThroughProxy, just CustomProxy.

Anyone got this problem?

Below is my sample custom proxy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="FileService" transports="http https" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <property name="file.md5.path" expression="//*[local-name() = 'filePath']" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <class name="testowe.mediators.file.md5"/>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <exam:OutputType xmlns:exam="http://example.com/">
                        <exam:result>$1</exam:result>
                    </exam:OutputType>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:file.md5.result"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence>
            <log level="full" description="Blad w faulcie"/>
            <makefault version="soap11">
                <code xmlns:soap11Env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" value="soap11Env:Client"/>
                <reason expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE"/>
                <role/>
            </makefault>
            <send/>
        </faultSequence>
    </target>
    <publishWSDL key="conf:testowe/schemas/FileService.wsdl">
        <resource location="FileService.Messages.xsd" key="conf:testowe/schemas/FileService.Messages.xsd"/>
    </publishWSDL>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with WSO2-ESB 4.8.1 PPT (Pass Through Transport), ESB is not responding in case of malformed xml. Same has been fixed in 4.9.0 [ESBJAVA-3284](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-3284)

Comment: I was afraid of that... Thanks for your answer :)